# Linq to XML without knowing how many descendants there are

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I am looking at an XML file that looks as follows:

```
<test>
   <vehiclenumber>123</vehiclenumber>
   <form>
     <form_id>1</form_id>
     <datafield>
         <fieldnumber>1</fieldnumber>
         <data>
            <datawords>
               <datatext1>1234</datatext1>
               <mc2>656865</mc2>
            </datawords>
         </data>
      </datafield>
   </form>
</test>
```

Currently I have the following code:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> elements = documentXDoc.Descendants("test");

            _fuelReceipts.AddRange(elements
                .Select(receipt => new Receipt()
                {
                    vehicle_number = receipt.Element("vehiclenumber") == null ? "" : receipt.Element("vehiclenumber").Value,
                    field = receipt.Descendants("datafield")
                    .Select(x => new Field()
                    {
                        field_number = x.Element("fieldnumber") == null ? "" : x.Element("fieldnumber").Value,
                        event_data = x.Descendants("data")
                        .Select(y => new FieldData()
                        {
                            event_data = y.Value
                        }).ToList()
                    }).ToList()
                }));
        }
```

The problem here is that for the `<data>` I don't know how many descendant are going to be in there or what they will be called. Is there a way to parse these out seperately without knowing this information? Right now, I would be getting something like 1234656865, when actually I want 1234 in an object and 656865 in a seperate one within the same object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your inner "data" select to that:

```
event_data = x.Descendants("data").Descendants().Where(d => !d.HasElements).Select(y => y.Value).ToList()
```

This will give a list of `string` with two elements: 1234 and 656865. You can easily join it to one string using `String.Join()` method:

```
event_data = String.Join(" ", x.Descendants("data").Descendants().Where(d => !d.HasElements).Select(y => y.Value).ToList())
```

Comment: When I do this, I get an error on the ToList() at the end. It is trying to convert a generic.list to my business object. Right now the business object is just public string event_data { get; set; }, what should it be for this to work?

Comment: I edited my answer. `event_data` should be `List<string>` or `IEnumerable<string>`. If you want just a string with space as a delimiter use the second example, with `String.Join()`

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the names of the XML descendants are meaningful. This code puts them in a  dictionary as it extracts them into the Field object.

```
void Main()
{
    string input = "<test><vehiclenumber>123</vehiclenumber><form><form_id>1</form_id><datafield>";
    input += "<fieldnumber>1</fieldnumber><data><datawords>";
    input += "<datatext1>1234</datatext1><mc2>656865</mc2>";
    input += "</datawords></data></datafield></form></test>";

    XDocument documentXDoc = XDocument.Parse(input);
    IEnumerable<XElement> elements = documentXDoc.Descendants("test");

    IEnumerable<Receipt> _fuelReceipts =  elements
        .Select(receipt => new Receipt()
        {
            vehicle_number = receipt.Element("vehiclenumber") == null ? "" : receipt.Element("vehiclenumber").Value,
            field = receipt.Descendants("datafield")
            .Select(x => new Field()
            {
                field_number = x.Element("fieldnumber") == null ? "" : x.Element("fieldnumber").Value,
                event_data = x.Elements("data").Descendants()
                    .Where(d => !d.HasElements)
                    .ToDictionary(d => d.Name.LocalName, d => d.Value)
            }).ToList()
        });
}

class Receipt {
    public string vehicle_number { get; set; }
    public List<Field> field { get; set; }
}

class Field {
    public string field_number { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> event_data { get; set; }
}
```